# how to repeat the game if the answer wrong in the code android

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got a problem. This game has a level, at every level has a number of different questions, the next level will open if the previous level was completed to answer. the problem is, I have to make this game to repeat the same questions if the questions can not be answered. but if the listing is like this, the game will repeat to the problems that exist at the beginning of the game if the answer is wrong. I use the database, c = the name of the database, and x = the value at each level (the number of questions that must be answered in one level). I desperately need your help all. thanks for your attention.
The code that makes this game will repeat the questions that appear at the beginning of the game if a wrong answer :

```
if (AhoCorrasick.nodes[node].leaf) {
        if (trueanswer.equals(answer)){
            popup();
        }else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Question.this);
            builder1.setMessage("your answer is wrong")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNeutralButton("Try Again",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            c.moveToPosition(Level.x);

                            tvhint.setText(c.getString(2));
                            etanswer.setText("");

                        }
                    }).show();
        }
```

This code to a value at every level :

```
public void level1(View oView) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Level.this, Question.class));
    x = 0;                           
}

public void level2(View oView) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Level.this, Question.class));
    x = 6;

}

public void level3(View oView) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Level.this, Question.class));
    x = 14;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Avoid saying you need help, we already know that. Also, avoid thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be like i would have a list of question objects.... And have a radom pick of question from list.. And delete each question from list on answering it right.. When no more questions left in list that means all questions are answered right.. N move to next activity